# How to retain/remember Source Control sort order in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode source control I select "sort by status".  However that setting is not retained across launches of vscode.

Is there a way to set the default value?

Is there a way for vscode to remember the last selected value?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug/feature request ticket about this
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127952

Make sure to upvote it, if you'd want to see this fixed/implemented.